# Matplotlib cannot be shown

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to visualize pandas.DataFrame using matplotlib on linux.
My code is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sep = "\n\n\n"

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
print("df:")
print(df, end=sep)

print("Info:")
print(df.info(), end=sep)

print("Description:")
print(df.describe(), end=sep)

df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(25, 15))
df.hist(bins=20, figsize=(25, 15))
plt.show()
```

But it says:

```
UserWarning: FigureCanvasAgg is non-interactive, and thus cannot be shown
  plt.show()
```

I tried to add tkinter backend with:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

But it cannot find agg, although I have tkinter, and gives:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

So, are there any options to show plot without installing additional libraries?

python 3.10, matplotlib 3.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe installed Python **without tcl/tk support**?

On Linux you might need to do [this](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-python-tkinter-on-linux/).

On Win I had to tick it and the issue got fixed:
[image: Python installation window]

Comment: Yep.  I don't know why I didn't include the tcl/tk feature, but modifying the installation and adding support for this did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on similar [problem](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/figurecanvasagg-interactivity-problem/24042) you can try install pyqt5:

> python -m pip install PyQt5

And if that didn't help you can check out this [tutorial](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781789135718/1/ch01lvl1sec04/working-in-non-interactive-mode) about working in non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed PyQt6, try to uninstall it and install PyQt5.

```
pip uninstall PyQt6
pip install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 0):

Install python3-tk package seems to work for me. I'm on Ubuntu by parallels(M1 Mac).

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```